# How to align Label to the right side of header in SemanticUI

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I want to have a Menu header item, with counter in a label located on the right side of the header.
Currently I have

```
| Projects [label]      |
```

instead of

```
| Projects       [label]|
```

Here is my code:

```
<div className="header">
   Projects
   <div className="ui label floated left pointing" id="projectsMenuCounter"><div className="ui active mini inline loader inverted"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<div className="header">
   Projects
   <div  style="float:right;" className="ui label floated left pointing" id="projectsMenuCounter"><div className="ui active mini inline loader inverted">[label]</div></div>
</div>
```

Or

```
.floated {
  float:right;
}
```